# Numeric axis labels in incorrect order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following generated data frame called Raw_Data:

```
    Time Velocity Type
1    10        1    a
2    20        2    a
3    30        3    a
4    40        4    a
5    50        5    a
6    10        2    b
7    20        4    b
8    30        6    b
9    40        8    b
10   50        9    b
11   10        3    c
12   20        6    c
13   30        9    c
14   40       11    c
15   50       13    c
```

When plotting each Type, with the following:

```
ggplot(Raw_Data, aes(x=Time, y=Velocity))+geom_point() + facet_grid(Type ~.)
```

the y-axis increments as:

```
1, 11, 13, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

The y-axis labels should be in order - why has 11 and 12 appeared after 1?

Comment: Can you show a dput of your example?  Try by calling `Raw_Data$Velocity <- factor(Raw_Data$Velocity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the data frame as follows using your sample data:

```
mydata <- read.table(text="Time Velocity Type
1    10        1    a
2    20        2    a
3    30        3    a
4    40        4    a
5    50        5    a
6    10        2    b 
7    20        4    b
8    30        6    b
9    40        8    b
10   50        9    b
11   10        3    c
12   20        6    c
13   30        9    c
14   40       11    c
15   50       13    c", header=TRUE)
```

Followed by the command

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Time, y=Velocity))+geom_point() + facet_grid(Type ~.)
```

which correctly displays the plot as shown in picture below
[image: Plot]

**Note:** changing the call to `ggplot` as shown below:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Time, y=as.character(Velocity))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(Type ~.)
```

reproduces the problem you mentioned. So you need to convert the `Velocity` variable to appropriate type i.e. `integer` in your case.

Comment: It is better to include above comment in the answer, instead of in a comment.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus, included the comment inside answer as you suggested.