# Why ggplot2 geom_boxplot gives wrong order results for no reason?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have been using ggplot2 with `geom_boxplot` to plot multiple boxplots in one graph. The data looks something like thst below.

```
Month   Rainfall

1         45
1         12
1         14
2         65
2         45
2         78
3         10
3         35
3         92
.         .
.         .
.         .
```

So by using boxplot I want to see the boxplot for the values of Rainfall for each group (1,2,3...). The result I am getting is weird and order seems messed up. Any help?

```
ggplot(data=edit3)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=Month, y=Rainfall))
```

Note: edit3 is the dataframe with the values of Rainfall and Month.

[image]

```
dput(head(edit3[,c("Month","Rainfall")],9))
```

```
structure(list(Month = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2"), Rainfall = c(NA, 135.6, 34.2, 39.4, 134.6, 234.6, 69.6, 
92.8, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: The Months are ordered lexicographically, most likely because that column is a character or a factor. Convert it to a numeric column.

Comment: Not sure what the best duplicate would be, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38413264/324364) or, possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/324364)

Comment: I just tried this using `edit3$Month <- as.integer(edit3$Month)` and the result is only one boxplot of the total values of Rainfall. Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks, I will check both. Could not find a duplicate.

Comment: Not without an actual reproducible example to work with. But I can tell you with 100% certainty that the ordering you're seeing is because that column was originally either a character or factor. If it was a factor, then `as.integer` won't necessarily convert it the way you want. Se my second link.

Comment: Following up on joran's last comment, if your variable is a factor you need to convert it to text before converting to numeric. Try `edit3$Month = as.integer(as.character(edit3$Month))`.

Comment: I see that `typeof(edit3)` is list.  I have been working the data with dplyr and tidyr, not sure why list. But `typeof(edit3$Month)` is integer.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of ```dput(head(edit3[,c("Month","Rainfall")],9))```?

Comment: Huh, I thought for some reason ggplot would do multiple boxplots for an integer x axis, but clearly it does not. You have to make it a factor, but specify the order of the levels.

Comment: Ah, there you go, you can do with integer x axis, you just also have to specify `group = Month`.

Comment: `edit3`'s type is a list because data frames are lists—they're lists of columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numeric axis labels in incorrect order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413264/numeric-axis-labels-in-incorrect-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your months are like factors, you just need to reorder the factors. Here I used the `forcats` package for this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

edit31_1 <- edit3 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Month = forcats::fct_inorder(Month))

ggplot2::ggplot(edit31_1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Month, y = Rainfall))
```

[image]

---

- Fictitious data used:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
edit3 <- data.frame(Month = as.factor(rep(paste(seq(1, 12, 1)), 3)),
                    Rainfall = rnorm(n = 36, mean = 60, sd = 30))

ggplot2::ggplot(edit3) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Month, y = Rainfall))
```

[image]